# The UICollectionView can not scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have add a a collectionView in UIController ,but after I added it find that the collectionView can't scroll .
[Init method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6hrU.jpg)   [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPIaf.jpg)

1.The cell's position is correct,and it can respond click .

2.If I don't set the property alwaysBounceVertical = Yes, the collectionView can't move ,after I added it ; the collectionView will always back to the origin place. I can see the below cell when bouncing .

I've tried

1.Use the UICollectionViewController replace the UIViewController.

2.Set the defaults property related scrollDirection.

Comment: Have you enabled paging?

Comment: @Ermal Kaleci  ,tried that ,doesn't work ..

Comment: Post any piece of code so we can have a better idea what you are doing.

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Thanks , It's been solved after I override the flowLayout method  -(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize .

Comment: collectionView cannot determine paging count without content size so it will scroll always on top as it has a page. This was way I asked if you have enabled paging . Best, Ermal

Answer (score 1):

sorry for maybe stating the obvious, but have you tried?

```
[[self collectionView] setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Just mentioning this because you don't describe having tried this in your question.